# How to insert a new record if old record is updated?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, csv

I am using mysql as my database for a php application.

I have to parse a csv sheet, and insert the data into the database only if old record is updated.

One way is to get the records from database using Ids I have in my csv and then check for values, if there is a difference then add a new record, but because I have data in hundreds of MBs I cannot do this back and forth from database, is there a way of doing it completely in sql ?

Id isn't unique, the new record that has to be inserted will use the same id.

For e.g. following is the current record
| 1001 | M Danish | Singapore |

and country changes to  USA, table will have two rows as follows
| 1001 | M Danish | Singapore |
| 1001 | M Danish | USA |

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Show us something you have done. Table structure, data structure... Is the id unique? What will be the id of the new row inserted if the csv id says that the record in the dub with the same id has been updated?

Comment: @rjdown this updates the same record, i don't have to change that. I have to add a new one.

Comment: MySQL does not have `instead of` triggers, So I suggest you solve it programatically, either with a PHP function Or a MySQL Stored Procedure.

Comment: Btw: what will happen the second time you will run the csv load? You will have to compare two rows in db against one in csv? Are all the information supposed to change?

Comment: create UNIQUE INDEX on current table and then use REPLACE INTO instead of INSERT INTO

Comment: @LelioFaieta I must say I am dumb in this area, I will have to add a last updated column and check against the latest one

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from your question you can make another raw in your database table name "updated" values 0 or 1 (false or true) before you insert csv data to database check for that record then do your actions as its value (false or true)

Answer (score 0):

Roundtrips to the DB are typically quite expensive in terms of relative costs. When facing this type of situation, I usually try to store a local map (i.e., a PHP array with string keys) with the values to compare, allowing me to only roundtrip the updates/inserts required by the DB.

Here's an overly-simplified example for the sake of illustration:

```
// variable created in php file from previous run
$records = [
    "1001 | M Danish | Singapore" => true
    // ... other records
];
// check if value present, a constant time operation on a map
if (!isset($records["1001 | M Danish | USA"])) {
    // insert into db
}
```

Of note, the above example does not iterate through all the records, handle duplicate keys, deletion of old keys, etc. However, hopefully it gives you the general idea for greatly reducing the DB roundtrips (or the overall size of one roundtrip) by doing some quick work in PHP before making the query.

Comment: This is a good solution, but I have more than 50K records, with 21 columns, and it grows with time, so it would not be feasible to keep all that data in memory

Comment: @mdanishs It doesn't all have to be stored in memory.  The map can be broken up (sharded) across multiple files by id or some other combination of fields (similar to large DBs.)

Comment: @mdanishs Additionally, you could store a checksum/hash instead of column values for watching for changes, and this would save on memory.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your table a auto increment Id. Then in php run a query to select the last Id that match your row in csv. Compare the two and insert if there are differences. This is the most efficient way I can think of with your table structure.

I would create a table with data that do not change and a table with duplicates id(csv Id) where you will insert only on changes. This will make things a lot easier and quicker for you. The second table will have an auto increments Id to check for the last row with the same Id from csv.

Hope it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

you can run insert ignore on duplicate key update sql.
This will work only if you have a unique key define in the column/s you want to be unique

```
insert ignore into table1(col1, col2) 
values ('val1', 'val2')
on duplicate key update
col1 = VALUES(`col1`),
col2 = VALUES(`col2`)
```

this will update row with values val1, val2, or insert if the row wa not found

if you have a lot of inserts/updates you can use this with bulks

```
insert ignore into table1(col1, col2) 
values 
('val1', 'val2'),
('val3', 'val4'),
('val5', 'val6'),
('val7', 'val8'),
('val9', 'val10'),
('val11', 'val12'),
('val13', 'val14')
on duplicate key update
col1 = VALUES(`col1`),
col2 = VALUES(`col2`)
```